# RemoteView and setGravity

Tags: android, android-widget, remoteview

I've got an android widget, that displays a `TextView` in a `FrameLayout`. The `TextView` fills the whole parent layout.
What I want to do, it be able to change at runtime where will the text will appear within the `TextView`.

Currently, I'd do it by changing the gravity on the TextView... It even has a `setGravity(int)` method, which should work perfectly with a RemoteView (I'm in a widget, remember?).. In theory anyway.

Unfortunately, this comes back with an error. Something about "cannot run `setGravity(int)` here" or sth. Will update with the exact error message if needed

I'm using this snippet:

```
myRemoteView.setInt(R.id.myTextView, "setGravity", myGravity);
```

Anyone tried this before, and has any ideas?

Comment: Any better solution for this? I also cannot "setGravity" of LinearLayout on RemoteView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work but, if not, maybe you could have two textviews and switch the visibility from GONE to VISIBLE to get the text at the right place.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Well, that's what I ended up doing at the moment.. Unfortunately, having two of these textviews, with 3 gravity options means I have to manage 6 of them, with some nasty switch statements..

Comment: And considering the fact that I also want to change the shadow color.. It's getting much much worse :(

Comment: Try to override the setGravity of a custom TextView class to see if it's called in the right way...could help...

Comment: Can't use custom classes in a RemoteView >_<

Comment: Considering nothing else came up, and I couldn't find anything betterm after tons of research - that is the best/only solution.. Accepted the answer )

Comment: @ArtiomChilaru, you can use custom classes in `RemoteViews`. See [RemoteViews.RemoteView annotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#nestedclasses)

Comment: @StenaviN can that be used with android widgets as well?

Comment: @ArtiomChilaru, I don't know. Try yourself and share your experience.

Comment: Nope, seems like it's not possible after all. I just get errors stating that it can't load the class.. Seems like inside app widgets it can only load the classes defined within the framework itself